# Function onsubmit is not executed for some reason

Tags: javascript

I have a form like this:

`<form action="/register" name="formz" id="formz" novalidate onsubmit="return valForm()" method="POST">`

And I have a function:

```
function valForm() {
  document.getElementById("formz").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    if (checkuser() === true || checkpass() === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

This function is not even executed, ever as I see from using debugger in Chrome. 
Any help on why could that be?

JIC the rest of the script file (the two other functions):

```
function checkuser() {
  $.getJSON("/check?username=" + document.forms["formz"]["username"].value, function(data) {
    let x = document.forms["formz"]["username"].value;
    let vard = data.available;

    if (vard == true && x) {
      document.getElementById("username").classList.remove('is-invalid');
      document.getElementById("username").classList.add('is-valid');
      return true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("username").classList.remove('is-valid');
      document.getElementById("username").classList.add('is-invalid');
      return false;
    }
  });
}

function checkpass() {
    let x = document.forms["formz"]["password"].value;
    if (!x) {
      document.getElementById("password").classList.remove('is-valid');
      document.getElementById("password").classList.add('is-invalid');
      return true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("password").classList.remove('is-invalid');
      document.getElementById("password").classList.add('is-valid');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `valForm` function in order to add the event listener to the form?

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: You may remove the event listener because your function is called when the form is submitted.

Comment: use onsubmit="myFunction()"
and in form you should have the button that can submit form or    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit

Comment: @mgarcia onsubmit within the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete return

```
<form action="/register" name="formz" id="formz" novalidate onsubmit="valForm()" method="POST">
```

and delete adding "onsubmit" event listener because you already added to form on HTML.

Correct valForm function:

```
function valForm() {
  if (checkuser() === true || checkpass() === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! JS has an ability to magically drain all my energy and desire to learn in an instant :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem here seems to be that you never execute anything when you submit. Why? Because the function you use as `onsubmit` simply adds an event listener to your form on **the very same event**. But, since the event already happened, nothing of your actual code is executed.

To fix it you have two options:

- Ditch `addEventListener` and simply run your code inside `valForm`.
- Ditch `onsubmit` and call `addEventListener` the moment the page loads, instead of waiting for another function call.